# How to add javascript variable in Utag.link telium

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add javascript variable in Utag.link in Telium implementation.
 i have a variable like:

```
Var data = "data-details"
```

(It is coming dynamically from ajax call and value is combination of string, numeric and underscore).

My utag.link is :

```
Utag.link(utag_view=
              {key:"value1", 
               key1:"value2", 
               })
```

in place of value2, i want to pass data instead of value2, which is getting fetch dynamically

Comment: Try declare utag_view variable first and change it's field like this ->   utag_view["key1"] = data after you get data from ajax. Than use Utag.link()

Comment: Can you please help me with an example. Again, i want to mention that if we are using alert to print data/data-details, it is showing the dynamic data in alert box, but inside utag.link, not able to extract the value.